How does numpy.polyfit return a slope and y-intercept when its documentation says it returns otherwise?
I have seen examples where slope, yintercept = numpy.polyfit(x,y,1) is used to return slope and y-intercept, but the documentation does not mention "slope" or "intercept" anywhere.
The documentation also states three different return options:

p: ndarray, shape (deg + 1,) or (deg + 1, K)
Polynomial coefficients, highest power first. If y was 2-D, the coefficients for k-th data set are in p[:,k],


or

residuals, rank, singular_values, rcond
These values are only returned if full == True

residuals: sum of squared residuals of the least squares fit
rank: the effective rank of the scaled Vandermonde
singular_values: singular values of the scaled Vandermonde
rcond: value of rcond,



or

v: ndarray, shape (deg + 1, deg + 1) or (deg + 1, deg + 1, K)
Present only if full == False and cov == True


I have also run code with exactly the previous line and the slope and yintercept variables are filled with a single value each, which does not fit any of the documented returns. Which documentation am I supposed to use, or what am I missing?


slope, yintercept = numpy.polyfit(x, y, 1) 


Both full and cov parameters are False, so it's the first option, "Polynomial coefficients, highest power first". deg is 1, so "p: ndarray, shape (deg + 1,)" is an array of shape (2,).
With tuple assignment,

slope is p[0], the xdeg-0 = x1 coefficient,
yintercept is p[1], the xdeg-1 = x0 coefficient.


That was not obvious for me at all. So, it is returning [m,b] from y=mx+b, if I give points with 2 dimensions?

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "points with 2 dimensions" (or what other points you would give), but yes.
